# Google Sheets: Updating data in an existing row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just a couple of weeks into my coding adventure. I am trying to build a sheet that will edit values in existing cells based on the value in another cell. I was able to write a script that would write a new row in the database based on the values in the dashboard when the script was run.

```
function submitClientContact() {
      var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("New Client Form"); //Form Sheet
      var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Info for Sales"); //Data Sheet
      
      //Input Values
      var values = [[formSS.getRange("E4").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E3").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E5").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C8").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C10").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C12").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C13").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C14").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C16").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C17").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C18").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C19").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C20").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C21").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C22").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C24").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C25").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C26").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C27").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C28").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C29").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("C30").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E8").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E9").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E10").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E11").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E12").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E13").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E14").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E16").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E17").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E18").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E19").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E20").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E21").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E22").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E24").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E25").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E26").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E27").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E28").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E29").getValue(),
                     formSS.getRange("E30").getValue()]];
      
      datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 45).setValues(values);
    
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("New Client Form");
      sheet.getRange("E3:E5").clearContent();
      
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("New Client Form");
      sheet.getRange("C8:C30").clearContent();
      
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("New Client Form");
      sheet.getRange("E8:E30").clearContent();
    
}
```

I now need a script to edit the cells in the database. The sheet will have 3 primary functions. 1 dropdown containing all of the clients in the database (cell A1), 1 row to show the data that is in the database for that client (column A), and one row that would be used to edit that existing data (column B). I can build the lookup equations easily, but I need help with the script to edit the database.

I basically need a script that will use the data in the drop down (A1) to reference the row in the database in which data needs to be edited, followed by editing all 45 columns but leaving blank cells (blank in column B) alone.

I assume it is just a couple of lines that I am missing to make this work, but I have been struggling with this for far too many hours.

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly showing the desired output?

Comment: I would reorganize my spreadsheet to make my coding easier.